# Ejabberd MySQL Schemas

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I have 2 separate ejabberd servers, both are 19.05 and use mysql as the default DB.
But one server uses the normal mysql schema and the other uses the new schema.

Is it possible to migrate the old schema to the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at those release notes https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-17-11-happy-birthday-ejabberd/ they say:

> As an experimental feature, if you compile from sources with option
>   ‘–enable-new-sql-schema’, an extra server_host columns will be used in
>   your SQL tables. This feature allows to use the same database for all
>   your vhosts. See ‘**ejabberdctl update_sql**’ command to update your sql
>   schema in order to try this feature.

To use that command, you must first enable a small module that provides it:

```
modules:
  mod_admin_update_sql: {}
```